# JSON date format for Highstocks

Tags: php, json, integer, highcharts

I am trying to retrieve data from database using json and use it to build highstocks  chart but problem is date format, i am getting unix timestamps in milliseconds . Its stored as float type but when i fetch it , it displays as string . i even used int conversion but then it gives 2147483647 (because its a big number. please help
**Here is the output for PHP page (json callback)**

```
[
["1380648572000",224],
["1380648594000",223]
]
```

Here is jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/c8mKp/

Comment: those are javascript timestamps. Simply lop off the right-most 3 characters to get seconds. It's not as good as rounding, but since you can't round the oversized numbers anyways, chopping off is the next best thing.

Comment: thats not the problem, problem is array shouldnt have quotes. "1380648572000" should be 1380648572000. its float datatype how do i fix it and return to json_encode ?? thanks for help though

Comment: You're on a 32bit PHP. You can *NOT* have integers larger than 2147483647. The quotes are forcing PHP to see those numbers as strings, preserving all the digits for you.

Comment: is there a work around for this ???

Comment: Sure. Upgrade to a 64bit version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like incorrect json encoding, but you should use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK as flag or use string and then parse by parseFloat() each x value.

Comment: Tried JSON_NUMERIC_CHCEK and this is what i get 

[1.380648572e+12,224],[1.380648594e+12,223]

Comment: You need to prepare your data as float without mathematical power.

Comment: not possible its not mathematical power , its float error in big numbers